# Is there a equivalent syntax of [SomeClass class] in Swift?

Tags: objective-c, swift

In Objecive-C,I can use this syntax like [SomeClass class] to obtain the class type of some class,for example:

```
if ([someInstance isKindOfClass:[SomeClass class]]) {
       // do something
}
```

But,how I do the same thing in Swift?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

In Swift, classes do not automatically have a base class. You can't use `isKindOfClass` unless
your class is a subclass of `NSObject`.

For checking an instance is a subtype, use the `is` operator:

```
class Animal {}
class Dog: Animal {
    func bark() { println("woof!") }
}
class Cat: Animal {
    func meow() { println("mew!") }
}

var fluffy:Animal = Cat()

if fluffy is Dog {
    println("fluffy is a dog")
} else if fluffy is Cat {
    println("fluffy is a cat")
}
```

The problem is, even though you know *fluffy* is a `Cat`, you still have to cast it to call `meow()`:

```
(fluffy as Cat).meow()
```

or:

```
let mycat = fluffy as Cat
mycat.meow()
```

In Swift, it is common to check the subclass with `as?` like so:

```
if let mydog = fluffy as? Dog {
    mydog.bark()
} else if let mycat = fluffy as? Cat {
    mycat.meow()
}
```

Or with `as` in a switch statement:

```
switch fluffy {
case let mydog as Dog:
    mydog.bark()
case let mycat as Cat:
    mycat.meow()
default:
    println("something else")
}
```

Comment: "You can't use isKindOfClass unless your class is a subclass of NSObject" Actually you can. After importing Foundation, try `(fluffy as AnyObject).isKindOfClass(...)`

Comment: That's interesting @newacct.  Never say never (or can't)!  Of course, why would you do that when `fluffy is Cat` is much shorter and clearer than `(fluffy as AnyObject).isKindOfClass(Cat)`.

Comment: If you found that my answer satisfactorily answered your question, please tick the checkmark next to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The correct syntax is

```
if someInstance.isKindOfClass(SomeClass)
```

Comment: I got an error: `SomeClass does not have a member named 'isKindOfClass'`